# How to define one-to-one or zero relationship in EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework, one-to-one

I have a **Student** entity that has a foreign key **HouseID** which refers to column **GeneralID** in general table. Am i defining it correctly in my model?

**Student.cs**

```
public class Student
{
    public int studentID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> houseID { get; set; }
    public virtual House House { get; set; }
  }

 public class House
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Student"), Column("GeneralID")]
    public int houseID { get; set; }

    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE**
My OnModelCreating() in GEDBContext class contains

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
            .HasOptional<House>(s => s.House)
            .WithOptionalDependent(h => h.Student);
```

**UPDATE 2**

I have changed the Student and House classes as follows:

```
 public class House
{
    [Key, Column("GeneralID")]
    public int houseID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public int studentID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("HouseID")]
    public Nullable<int> houseID { get; set; }
    public virtual House House { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: I dont think its a good idea to mix attribute and fluent syntax, it will just make things more confusing

Comment: What do you mean by *general table*? Is `House` a subclass?

Comment: We have a general table that has id, name, type columns the id could be houseid and name could be house name when type field is 3 or it could have id as groupid and name as group name when type field is 5 and so on. Now i want to use the houdeid field in my students table to link to this table so i can show house name on ui(grid)

Comment: So is House a sublass? How do you map this table to your entities? I'm pretty sure you can't have its primary key point to `Student` if it has to store multiple entity types.

Comment: I have changed house class as: **[Key, Column("GeneralID")]
    public int houseID { get; set; }** and Student class too. see UPDATE 2 in  my post

Comment: I am using CodeFirst Existing DB model